# Does the HTTP protocol contain any message integrity checking features?

Tags: php, ios, http

I've written an iOS app that uses HTTP to talk between server and device, and a small issue from the past has come up as something that needs to be addressed.  Specifically, how to check for / verify message integrity -- has the data somehow gotten corrupted between server and device.  The original issue may have been an encoding issue, or it could have been data actually getting messed up between device and server (the wi-fi on site was...  unfortunate).  Encoding is one thing I need to work on, but I also need to check, test, and fix the later issue.

I quickly came up with a solution based on an MD5 hash.  That's a great idea.  But it was os obvious that it occurred to me that before I start digging in and programming it, I should take the time to step back and ask myself, 'Has someone already written this for me?'

I'm going to look up libraries for the problem, but something that hit me is that it seems like an obvious idea to put that type of code somewhere in the network stack.  Somewhere, not to be too blunt, that's re-useable,and preferably fairly low level.  In fact, though I don't know whether or not it's the case, it seems almost logical that that should be handled automatically and transparently, without any need to invoke it.  I tried googling the subject, but...  I don't know if I even know the right keywords, as what I managed to pull up was usually stuff like verifying amazon SMS messages, checking your AT&T text messages online, and similarly useless junk, half of which I swear didn't even involve the HTTP protocol (maybe google ignores the HTTP keyword, or just uses it to restrict itself to HTTP sites and not HTTPS?).

So:  does the HTTP protocol (or HTTPS), as handled by PHP and iOS, have any type of error-checking built in?  Am I wasting my time?

Comment: I'd say it is useless, for small files an integrity check isn't needed.

Comment: @N1xx1 who said anything about files?  I'm handing JSON strings around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed in the network stack.
For the specific example of HTTP, it's in TCP (transport layer), IP (v4 only) (link layer) and your transport layer.
While it is still possible for errors to be introduced which one of the lower layers does not pick up (checksum doesn't detect it, faulty hardware, faulty OS, whatever) it is far less likely than an error in the application logic.

Comment: Not what I was hoping to hear...  the only possible other source of issue I can come up with is some really weird character encoding issue which, honestly, I have no clue how to even begin to test for and correct.

Comment: @Ron Create a new question describing your problem and asking for pointers about where to begin? :P

Comment: @Sysphus Once I have enough data I may do that, but I don't at this point -- the data from the original bug was scrubbed to try and get the device working NOW.  Don't worry too muych, that was just me going 'oh great, and here I was hoping this was the issue... thanks for telling me I was an idiot, even if it makes more work'

Answer (score 3):

Answer to the central Question whether HTTP has some flow control or integrity check:

No by design.

You need to do that on an application level - if ever needed. In 99.99% of issues in communication between Server and Client, its the "home made software" causing problems and not the underlying infrastructure. And the remaining 0.01% wouldn't be discovered by any "integrity check" since there's simply no connection any longer.

Comment: In many of the "remaining 0.01%" cases an integrity check WOULD discover corruptions.  These cases are when HTTP is used to download a static file for which the integrity check is known.  For example, an automatic check of a known MD5 (or better yet, a SHA256) of a file would quickly confirm its authenticity or corruption.

Some "managed file transfer" and other specialized file transfer web applications include post-transfer, hash-based integrity checks (as do legacy FTP clients) for this reason.

Comment: @ftexperts you are almost right. What you mean is an integrity check of the payload transmitted via HTTP. There are primitives like content-length header etc. but nothing can tell you from an HTTP protocol level, whether the payload is ok. And that was OPs question.So. you have to do it on App level (and managed FTP clients are Applications).